# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 3128 when post data using Axios in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I want to store JSON data in a database using Axios in node js. This is my node js code

```
const axios = require('axios');

const url = 'http://api/api/master_ab_store';

axios.post(url, {
    "data":[{"external_id":"-000001","code":"- ","name":"INVESTINDO","Phone":"031-5482334","Address":"Jalan Kelapa Puyuh","status_ab":"A"}]
})
.then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
})
```

But i got an error like this

```
C:\cs_test>node index.js
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 3128
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '3128',
  config: {
    url: 'http://api/api/master_ab_store',
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"data":[{"external_id":"-000001","KodeAB":"- ","NamaAB":"SUMBER ARTHA INVESTINDO","Phone":"031-5482041-44","Fax":"031-5482048","Address":"Kedungdoro No. 60 Lantai 7;Jawa Timur;Surabaya;60251","status_ab":"A"}]}',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1',
      'Content-Length': 211,
      host: 'api'
    },
```

In postman, it's running well

[image]

How to fix this issue? help me because I'm newbie in node js

Comment: Make sure the URL `http://api/api/master_ab_store` is correct. `ENOTFOUND error means the domain that you are trying to reach is unavailable or wrong`

Comment: Are you serving the api on your local machine? If so I would expect the url to be somthing like `http://localhost:8080/api/api/master_ab_store` or `http://127.0.0.1:5001/api...`

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh when I test it on the postman, It's running well

Comment: @MarkDavich yes, the API on my local server. I make a dummy domain, I'm setting it on host file and vhost file xampp

Comment: @Rahmat Drrendi, Side note, what database are you using?  Does your post data need to be a string in the manner that `JSON.stringify(pojo)` produces in javascript? Are you using a node backend? or something else? Did you try putting a forward slash at the end of your url in the node frontend? like `url = ...master_ab_store/`

Comment: @MarkDavich I'm using Mysql for the database and using Lumen for the API. The Node js just running the API with JSON data to store to the database

Comment: @RahmatEffendi Can you add the screenshot of your request in Postman?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh done, on my questions

Comment: I'm not sure why there are 3 dots at the end of the URL, can you check it?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh I don't know when I click the URL input, the 3 dots is not display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my issue. This is because the server has a proxy. So when I remove it, it's running.
Thanks to @Mark Davich and @ĐăngKhoaĐinh for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your url (baseURL) is correct. I use the free version of [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to check my api calls. Is your data object supposed to be an array? If not your endpoint my not know what to do with it

I don't use Axios or promises the way you do, so here is an alternative version of what you are trying to do. Maybe you it will help. The `async/await` replace the `.then/.catch`

```
import Axios from "axios";

axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://api/api/master_ab_store',
  timeout: 10000,
  withCredentials: true
});

let data = {
  external_id: "-000001",
  code : "- ",
  name: "INVESTINDO",
  Phone: "031-5482334",
  Address: "Jalan Kelapa Puyuh",
  status_ab: "A"
}

async getData(data) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(url, data);
    console.log(res.data); // .then
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(err); // .catch
  }
}
```